# Richfaces 4 fileUpload redirect following uploadcomplete

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I would like to redirect to another page following the upload of a single file.  The source xhtml and destination xhtml are in the same directory.  I have tried returning a String in the fileUploadListenerMethod:

```
public String loadFills(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
  return "treeOrderRequestStatus";
}
```

but this does not result in a redirect.

I have also tried accomplishing it via faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/userpages/manualDataLoad.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{manualDataLoader.loadFills}</from-action>
    <to-view-id>/userpages/treeOrderRequestStatus.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/userpages/manualDataLoad.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>treeOrderRequestStatus</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/userpages/treeOrderRequestStatus.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

and neither of these worked.

Finally, I have tried executing a link triggered by the uploadcomplete event:

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{manualDataLoader.loadFills}"
    maxFilesQuantity="1" createTempFiles="false" uploadLabel="Import Fill Data"
    addLabel="Select Fill File">
  <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="redirect"/>
</rich:fileUpload>

<h:link id="redirect" outcome="treeOrderRequestStatus"/>
```

and still no dice.  In each of these attempts I have tried multiple different combinations of specifying the destination page (e.g.: including the .xhtml extension, including the directory, ...) but have not yet succeeded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `execute` attribute tag is to define the components that will be sent in the request to the server. You can try for now something like `<a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" onbegin="rich:clientId('redirect').click();" />`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this did not work either.  It does appear to refresh the page, but it does not navigate to the other page (I tried many combinations of specifying the other page).

Comment: Try changing it for `<h:commandButton id="redirect" action="treeOrderRequestStatus" />` (still, this is not a good solution, but it could work).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - thanks again but this also fails to navigate.  Any idea why the standard JSF navigation cannot be used to accomplish this?

Comment: Remove the navigation rules, set an action for your commandButton and check that the action is called, then in your action return your page name (treeOrderRequestStatus). You should make sure that the action is getting invoked (debug, log a message, anything).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - the click does not occur, the action is not called - thoughts?

Comment: Yes, maybe the `rich:clientId('redirect')` javascript is not working as it should. Replace it for `document.getElementById('yourFormName:redirect')` and try again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - thank you very much!  It works with commandLink as well (which is better for me because it doesn't show up on the page).  Though you say its not a good solution it is effective and I thank you for that.  Throw it in an answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute attribute tag is to define the components that will be sent in the request to the server. You can try clicking a link/button using the `uploadcomplete` JavaScript method from the `<rich:fileUpload>` tag component:

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{manualDataLoader.loadFills}"
    maxFilesQuantity="1" createTempFiles="false" uploadLabel="Import Fill Data"
    addLabel="Select Fill File">
  <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" onbegin="document.getElementById('yourFormName:redirect').click();" />
</rich:fileUpload>

<h:commandButton id="redirect" action="treeOrderRequestStatus" style="display: none"
    tabindex="-1" />
```

Also, it would be better if you erase those navigation rules in your faces-config.xml to keep the file clean of needless configurations.

Comment: The `outcome` attribute does not work for me.  I have to use `action="#{manualDataLoader.redirect}"` then return the page that way.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake by copy/pasting. I've updated the post with the correct code.